How exactly do you find shiurim in tosfos on the daf hachaim website?
How exactly do you find shiurim in tosfos on the daf hachaim website? I am looking for practical help navigating their site to find these shiurim.

There are no "shiurim in tosfos on the daf hachaim website".
Other sites do have it.

On DafYomi.co.il you can find an English point-by-point of Tosfot. The Tosfos for today's daf (BAVA METZIA 84) is here.
Feel free to add more sites.

